# Automate Proof Read by Software or scripts

Tags: applescript

How guys its a funny question but i need to ask with you all 
Is there any away to  automate proof reading in in-design or PDF files or any other option that can be done using applescript, or java or any other software.??

Comment: Can you provide a more succinct description on what expectation/requirements you have?

Comment: Thanks for the Response Frank.
I am trying to find a software or a script that checks the contents of In-design and word file ie to match the text and all special characters of in-design with the text of word file.
Mainly to compare both and display the error List.

Comment: You may have to consider exporting or converting the document to plain text so that you can then iterate through it for spell checking or other error conditions.